我的思念是不可触摸的网 - what is this metaphor?
The song 心雨 (Heart Rain) is mostly straightforward and I think I understand it. But the first line is obscure:
我的思念 是不可触摸的网

Literally, it means "My longing, is a net that can't be touched". I'm struggling to understand the artist's meaning.
Nets entangle and trap. Does the artist mean they can't escape from the feeling of attachment?
The next verse says "My longing is no longer a sea that lacks a dyke", so it would seem that whatever their state of mind may have been before, it's under control now.
Presumably the reason it can't be touched is that it's not a physical object but a psychological state.
Please help me to understand this metaphor.
For context, here is the entire song.
我的思念 是不可触摸的网
我的思念　不再是决堤的海
为什么总在　那些飘雨的日子
深深的把你想起

我的心事六月的情　沥沥下着心雨
想你想你想你想你　最后一次想你
因为明天我将成为别人的新娘
让我最后一次想你


Seems like I misheard the lyrics, I always thought it was 不在是缺堤的海 but it is actually 决堤的海 which changes the meaning somewhat.

不再是决堤的海 （初恋时的感情，像决堤的海，奔放无忌）

我的思念 - my longing
是不可触摸的网 - is a net that cannot be touched
Why is the net untouchable? Because it is all mental, it feels like an invisible net trapping me
Mental --> invisible --> cannot be touched
In other words: "I can't stop thinking of him"

我的思念不再是决堤的海 - My longing is no longer the sea that bursts its banks

If my longing is like a sea and the dam broke, I could freely let this feeling come out. On the other hand, if the dam is no longer broken, I could only keep it in my mind and could not express this feeling anymore

"I can't stop thinking of her" - I think it's a him, at least in the versions I have heard

Thanks, I start to see a connection between the first 2 verses now. Previously her longing was unconstrained, like a sea without a dam. Now there is a dam, she can't let her feelings out, so they are always there entangling her in a net that she can't touch. 因为明天她将成为别人的新娘。

untouchable is stronger than invisible. "I can do nothing about it".

One could still "see" something even if that something is "untouchable". But if something is "invisible" in the first place, there is no possibility of "touching" it because you would not know where exactly it is located. Thus my view is, the "net", a very common metaphor for being "trapped", in this case, within her nostalgic longing for a lost love is something she could not break free of because she could not even  "touch" it as it is all happening in her own mind.

Spider webs break easily. If she touches the web, it will break, and all that longing will break out again!
决提: 一般指堤岸被水冲开。
"我的思念是不可触摸的网"
"My longing is an untouchable web"
这句话表达了一种情感状态，
this phrase expresses a kind of emotional state,
其中"我"在尝试控制自己的感情，
in which "I" am trying to control my emotions,
希望驾驭自己的思想，
hoping to steer my thoughts,
不再让感情冲破理智的界限。
never again to let (my) emotions breakthrough the boundaries of reason,
这种表述方式通过比喻，
This kind of metaphor,
将思念比作一张无法触碰的网，
likens longing to an untouchable web,
形象地描绘了一种情感上的纠结和挣扎。
vividly depicting a kind of emotional entanglement and struggle,
同时，
At the same time,
"我的思念不再是决提的海"
"My longing (will) never again be a leaking ocean (of woes)"
进一步强调了这种控制，
further emphasises this kind of control,
表明虽然思念曾经如同泛滥的洪水，
makes clear that, even though ("my') longing once was like a surging flood,
但现在已经被束缚在某种形式中，
now (my emotions) are fettered after some fashion,
不再是无序的、破坏性的力量。
never again (will they be) a disorderly, destructive force.
因为明天我将成为别人的新娘
This does not bode well for the marriage!

You're saying that the web is untouchable, in the sense that it's fragile and will break if touched. This also makes sense, but it seems her emotions will always threaten to break out of their designated boundaries. So I agree with your last sentence!

网 could be 电网 power grid, and you could have a try

@NanningYouth: that's shocking!

心雨：我的思念是不可触摸的网
失恋的人处于深深的自我矛盾的心态。这句话表达思念的无处不在，就像处于一张网中。另一方面，这张网已经不能成为现实，是一种想象中的，是不可触摸到的。因为不可触摸，也就无法摆脱。
这首歌是男女对唱，双方对于彼此的爱情和另一种婚姻都是无奈。很难再有初恋时的奔放的海浪的体验，只能在内心深深地怀念。
